# Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, class, undefined-reference

I am learning about classes in c++, so I am writing the following simple code in separate files and while vscode is not showing any problems, the compiler is giving me an error when compiling.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "constants.h"
#include "cylinder.h"

int main ()
{
    Cylinder cylinder1(10,10);

    Cylinder cylinder2;

    std::cout << "volume : " << cylinder1.volume() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

cylinder.h

```
#ifndef CYLINDER_H
#define CYLINDER_H
#include "constants.h"

class Cylinder {
    
    public:

    Cylinder () = default;

    Cylinder (double rad_param, double height_param);

    double volume () { return PI * base_radius * base_radius * height; }

    double get_base_radius () { return base_radius; }
    double get_height () { return height; }
    void set_base_radius (double rad_param) {base_radius = rad_param; }
    void set_height (double height_param) {height = height_param; }

    private:

    double base_radius {1};
    double height {1};
};

#endif
```

cylinder.cpp

```
#include "cylinder.h"

Cylinder::Cylinder (double rad_param, double height_param)
    {
        base_radius = rad_param;
        height = height_param;
    }
```

constants.h

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

const double PI {3.1415926535897932384626433832795};

#endif
```

When I try to compile, I get this error:

> Starting build...
> C:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -std=c++23 "C:\PCHDD\Programming PCHDD\Learning\Template\main.cpp" -o "C:\PCHDD\Programming PCHDD\Learning\Template\main.exe"
> C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\90539\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6YTSXM.o: in function `main': C:/PCHDD/Programming PCHDD/Learning/Template/main.cpp:9:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to` Cylinder::Cylinder(double, double)'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Build finished with error(s).
>
> The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I did some search and found that it may be a linker error caused by not implementing a function, but all functions are implemented in the main.cpp ! I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to compile both `.cpp` files together.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you very much, I added #include "cylinder.cpp" to main.cpp and it worked.

Comment: No, don't **ever** include .cpp files. You have to edit your `tasks.json` to make vcode compile both files in the same `g++` execution. See duplicate for details.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen ok, thanks, I just read the answers to the question provided in duplicate, in tasks.json arguments, changed  "${file}" into "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp" , and problem solved, it is compiling successfully.